# Outlook Module sample throws "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: recipient"

Tags: outlook, manifest, outlook-addin

We have an Outlook Module Manifest that worked two weeks ago against Office 365 ([never against Exchange 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719008/outlook-sample-addin-added-but-it-is-not-shown)).

When we tried to remove it and add it again today, we got the following error message:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: recipient

[image]

We then tried to add the Outlook Module Manifest sample from [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-JavaScript-ModuleExtension/blob/master/outlook-add-in-javascript-moduleextension.xml), but that throws the same error message.

Any idea what we may be missing? Or did Microsoft change their Office 365 infrastructure, breaking their own sample?

Comment: should this be on SO, or on ServerFault?

Comment: @TimothyGroote Not sure whether the problem lies with the server or with the module developer (me). But if it is a server problem, I cannot fix it, because the server is in the cloud, so SO was my best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message may just want to tell you that your account does not have an Exchange Online license assigned right now. The account used to upload an extension for the organization requires a valid Exchange Online license.